# Chamar outra classe (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Como faço para chamar uma "classe" do tipo jFrame por exemplo a partir de minha classe principal?
O meu jFrame tem seu próprio main que dá o setVisible true para ele aparecer, porém eu queria acessar esse main dele a partir da minha classe principal , para poder dar setVisible pelo main dele ao invés de eu criar uma instancia do tal e dar o setVisible pela minha classe, até porque perde qualidade do design do frame.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que instanciar a classe [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) e chamar o método [`setVisible(boolean b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible-boolean-) com o parâmetro true.

```php
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame= new JFrame("PT Stack Overflow");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Caso seu objetivo seja herdar `JFrame` o procedimento é mesmo so que ao invés de instanciar `JFame`você instancia sua classe herdeira de `JFrame`:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;

class MeuFrame extends JFrame
{
   JLabel label;

  // constructor
  MeuFrame ( String titulo )
  {
    super( titulo );                      // invoca o constructor de JFrame
    setSize( 150, 100 );                 

    // Ajusta o comportamento de fechamento do JFrame
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    setLayout( new FlowLayout() );       
    label = new JLabel("PT Stack Overflow");  
    add( label );                        // adiciona o JLabel ao JFrame
  }

} 

public class TestFrame2
{
  public static void main ( String[] args )
  {        
    MeuFrame frame = new MeuFrame("Esse é o meu frame!");
    frame.setVisible( true );            

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui, para chamar o main de outra classe através da sua classe principal é  :

NomeDaClasse.main(args);

Comment: Não é dessa forma que se chama uma janela, é instanciando ela e dando um setVisible.

Comment: o setVisible é construído no main da própria janela

Comment: Depende da sua aplicação. Se você estiver usando mais de um JFrame, é uma pessima ideia. O mais comum é Ter somente uma Jframe, e outras janelas usar Jdialog, e quando abrir subjanelas, dar um setvisible(false) no frame pra ele esconder. Dessa forma, não precisa instanciar novamente. Não me leve a mal, mas isso parece gambiarra.

Answer (score -1):

Bom, se instanciar a classe consegue acessa-la, classe principal:

```
public static void main(String args[])
     {
        Aluno estudante = new Aluno();//Aluno é outra classe.
```

Era essa sua dúvida?

Comment: Não, tipo, o jframe tem seu próprio main,eu posso instanciá-lo desse modo,porém o design dele fica mais rústico, diferente de quando tenho um jframe como classe principal e nao uma classe comum